# Hardware Acceleration on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware-acceleration

Does Windows Server 2008 have hardware acceleration?

I tried to use WPF to make over 20,000 drawings. It only cause around 40% CPU in windows 7.

However, I run the same program on Windows Server 2008 with the same hardware configuration except that it has a dedicated graphical display card (GT 9500) while Windows 7 has only an onboard display card, it cause over 80% CPU.

So, does Windows Server 2008 have hardware acceleration? Or could I make it?

And how do I change the hardware acceleration setting?

Comment: Put Windows 7 on the Server machine and vice versa, then compare results. The assumptions you're making right now don't seem to be based on any reliable measurement.